# Is Visual Studio 2022 handle type promotion incorrectly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

AFAIK in C++ if you multiply two different type, the result will be in the larger type.
But in Visual Studio 2022, this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long a = 7182L * 300000;
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

the output is -2140367296, surely this is wrong ? or maybe something is wrong with my installation of Visual Studio ?
I try this with clang online and clang output 2154600000

Comment: Refresh [Fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Comment: What is the largest value that a `long` can store?  Find that out and you will know that neither compiler is wrong.

Comment: To put it another way, what is the value of [`std::numeric_limits<long>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) on your system? (The value is probably different for your online compiler. Both results are allowed by the standard.)

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
    // long a = 7182L * 300000;
    unsigned long a = 7182l * 300000;
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

This result: `2154600000` for me. Windows 10 x64 PC + Visual Studio 2022
So I think maybe `long` doesn't fit the result.